# My transparent objects overwrite opaque objects depth and always draw on top?

Tags: xna, c#, rendering, depth-buffer

I have set up an 'Order Independent Transparency' method for drawing my transparent objects.

The algorithm can be simplified as follows:

DrawOpaqueObjects()
DrawTransparentObjects()

Drawing the transparent objects uses the following render target setup:

```
        colourAccumulation = new RenderTarget2D(
            game.GraphicsDevice,
            game.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth,
            game.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight,
            false,
            SurfaceFormat.Rgba64,           // 16 bit floating point texture (required for alpha blending caculations)
            DepthFormat.None
            );

        depthComplexity = new RenderTarget2D(
            game.GraphicsDevice,
            game.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth,
            game.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight,
            false,
            SurfaceFormat.Rgba64,           // 16 bit floating point texture (required for alpha blending caculations)
            DepthFormat.None
            );
```

The transparent objects are combined with another render target texture that all the opaque objects are drawn to before hand:

```
        scene = new RenderTarget2D(
            graphicsDevice,
            graphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth,
            graphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight,
            false,
            SurfaceFormat.Color,
            DepthFormat.Depth16,        // Requires a depth format for objects to be drawn correctly (e.g. wireframe model surrounding model)
            0,
            RenderTargetUsage.PreserveContents
            );
```

They are combined as follows:

```
PixelShaderOutput PixelShaderFunction(VertexShaderOutput input)
{
PixelShaderOutput output;

// Background colour 'Cbg'
float4 BackgroundColour = tex2D(BackgroundSampler, input.TextureCoordinates.xy);

float4 SumColour = tex2D(Texture0Sampler, input.TextureCoordinates.xy);

// [Depth complexity]
// • Each time a pixel is written by the transparent object it adds 1 to the value [float4(1, 1, 1, 1)]
// • This is why a render target with 16-bits per channel is required (SurfaceFormat.Rgba64)
float n = tex2D(Texture1Sampler, input.TextureCoordinates.xy).r;

// If no transparent pixel has been drawn at this location, return the background colour
if (n == 0.0)   
{
    output.Colour = BackgroundColour;

    return output;
}

SumColour = Upscale(SumColour);
n = Upscale(n);

// Average colour 'C'
float3 AvgColour = SumColour.rgb / SumColour.a;

// Average alpha based on depth complexity 'A'
float AvgAlpha = SumColour.a / n;

// T = (1 - A) ^ n
float T = pow(abs(1.0 - AvgAlpha), n);

// [Weighted Average Formula]
// • Cdst = (C * A * (1 - (1 - A)^n) / A) + Cbg * (1 - A)^n
// • Cdst = (C * A * (1 - T) / A) + Cbg * T
// • Cdst = C * (1 - T) + Cbg * T;
output.Colour.rgb = AvgColour * (1 - T); 
output.Colour.rgb += BackgroundColour.rgb * T;
output.Colour.a = 1;

return output;
}
```

The problem is that all transparent objects are never obscured by the opaque objects drawn before hand as denoted by the yellow circle in the following picture:

[image: Transparent Depth Problem]

The depth test has to be disabled for the transparent objects but it is enabled for the opaque.

Why is this incorrect effect occurring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want depth *testing* enabled (so that opaque objects block transparent objects), but you want depth *write* disabled (so that transparent objects don't update the depth buffer, and don't occlude each other).

```
depthState.DepthBufferEnable = true; 
depthState.DepthBufferWriteEnable = false;
```

Comment: That's the same as 'DepthStencilState.DepthRead'.  I have tried that before but it makes no difference when combining the scene render target with the transparent objects render target.